# Wie sagt man "Out of the corner of my eye" auf Deutsch?

Tags: grammar, english-to-german

Wie sagt man "Out of the corner of my eye"?

> In der Ecke meines Auges habe ich gesehen, wie mein Bruder aus dem Haus ging.

Am I using the right word for "corner" or would another word serve better?

Comment: Here you could have found it: http://www.dict.cc/?s=augenwinkel&=DEEN&=

Comment: @c.p. Vorwärtssuche (en->de) ist hier geeigneter: http://www.dict.cc/?s=corner+of+the+eye

Comment: I clarified the question and wonder if can be re-opened in its current form. The OP made a plausible but wrong effort to translate "corner," using the wrong dictionary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct term in German is [*aus dem Augenwinkel*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Augenwinkel).

> Aus dem Augenwinkel sah ich, wie mein Bruder aus dem Haus ging.